# Displaying Array in Select - FORM API Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-fapi

I want to add key(type_id) and value(type_description) to select in drupal form API

$result_x->product_types->RPMProductType is array result from Database :- 
array(4) { [0]=>  object(stdClass)#18 (2) { ["type_description"]=>  string(10) "Calendered" ["type_id"]=>  int(1) } [1]=>  object(stdClass)#19 (2) { ["type_description"]=>  string(8) "Extruded" ["type_id"]=>  int(2) } [2]=>  object(stdClass)#20 (2) { ["type_description"]=>  string(6) "Molded" ["type_id"]=>  int(3) } [3]=>  object(stdClass)#21 (2) { ["type_description"]=>  string(5) "Other" ["type_id"]=>  int(4) } }

```
foreach ($result_x->product_types->RPMProductType as $data)
{

$form['manufacturer_add_new_sales']['product_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Product Type'),
    '#options'=>array($data->type_id=>$data->type_description),
    );
}
```

When do so I am getting only last value i.e Other.  How to correctly loop to bind Select to display all the array Key - Values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is my solution:- 

foreach ($resultx->product_types->RPMProductType as $type) 
{ 

 $select_options[$type->type_id] = $type->type_description; 

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create an array with values and use that.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $options[$key] = $value;
}
```

Then you can use $options as your options.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a function to return an array instead of setting each $key of the $options array.

```
'#options'=> function_options($param),
....
....
....

// Your Options populating function
function_options($param){
$optionarray = array();
// Populate array with DB values
.....
..... 
return optionarray;
}
```